# What is an envelope pattern in Pubsub messaging?

Tags: python, design-patterns, google-cloud-pubsub, envelope

I am looking for some resources in understanding the envelope pattern and google isn't being too helpful. Can someone illustrate this with an example? For more info, I am working with Pubsub in Python and I'm looking to tag messages with some additional info (apart from plainly adding that info in the message body) for complex applications.

Comment: Just like in real life: Write a letter. Put the letter in an envelope with an address. The envelope contains the letter *and* additional information so the mailing service can correctly deliver it. That is, the envelope is a *wrapping* object. Usually envelopes also contain rules (or implicit knowledge) of how to serialize content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The envelope pattern is a way to wrap a message with metadata to help determine what to do with that message without having to understand the contents of the message itself. The metadata can be used to determine how to route a message to the appropriate receiver to deal with the message contents or it could indicate what to do with the message itself.

Typically, the way this pattern works is that different layers add a wrapper on top of a message that is passed to it. There can be multiple, nested envelopes. When a message is received, there is a corresponding layer that removes one of the envelopes for every layer that added one.

The side that creates messages would look like this:

[image: Adding envelopes]

The side that consume messages would look like this:

[image: Remvoing evenlopes]

A Google Cloud Pub/Sub [message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#pubsubmessage) has an `attributes` map that can be used for precisely this purpose. You can put data in the attributes that can indicate what to do with the message without having to decode the bytes stored in the `data` portion of the message.

For example, imagine you have a topic that contains messages that correspond to different user actions on an ecommerce website. Some of the messages are for profile updates while others are transactions. You want to perform different actions on these types of messages. Instead of looking into the `data` field in the message to determine which type it is and what to do with it, you could add key/value pairs in the `attributes`, e.g. `action: UPDATE` and `action: TRANSACTION`. Then, your subscriber would look at the value for the `action` attribute and determine what to do with the message. It could execute a different piece of code or maybe even send it to a different service, acting as a router for messages. The key point is that the determination of what to do could be performed without having to decode the message data itself.

Messages sent to [push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push-subscription) endpoints have an [additional envelope added that indicates the subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receiving_push_messages) the message came from. This is necessary because it is possible for multiple push subscriptions to point to he same endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The PubSub envelope pattern is simple

- The message content (absolutely what you want, base64 encoded)
- Attributes on the message (that you can add to add meta data on the content). You can use attribute for taking decision on the message without processing it. *For exemple, add a message version. If your code can only process v1 and you have a v2 message, skip it instead of having unmarshalling error.*
- Id of publication
- Timestamp

When you consume the envelop, it is presented in 2 differents manner:

- [Cloud Function PubSub trigger event](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)
- [Push Subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push)

You will find the same information but not structured with the exact same JSON schema.

Comment: There are also [pull subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull), and the message passed to the client would have the attributes.

Comment: The pull subscription is not a special JSON envelope format because it's handle by the client library. That's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: I don't see how the JSON format is any more an envelope than what is passed into the pull subscriber. The JSON is just the encoding of a [PubsubMessage](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#pubsubmessage), which is the type of the object passed to the pull subscriber.

Comment: The difference is what you have to do. With pull subscription, the message are received with gRPC protocol and unpacked automatically by the client library. With JSON (in cloud function or in push subscription), you have to parse the JSON and to extract yourselves the data. And you don't to the same in both case.

Comment: I don't think your describing the salient part of the envelope pattern well. The contents of the message (the "data" portion) is just a set of bytes that have to be interpreted by the app. The data is wrapped in a PubsubMessage with the attributes, ID, and timestamp. This is true for JSON _and_ for the Protocol Buffer message. Perhaps there are multiple envelopes for a push subscription where the message is wrapped with the addition of the "subscription" field. But the distinction between the JSON-encoded message and the raw Protocol Buffer message isn't relevant to the envelope pattern.